# setting position dynamically

Tags: gwt, popup, jsni

I want to have the popup and then hiding and showing of this.This is completed
  and then I have made the label dynamic and with that label the popup is showing
 but now my main problem is this to set the popup with the screen as when the 
 screen get moved the popup will see the size of screen and it 
 adjust according up/down. I have tried out with finding of offsetHeight,
 offsetWidth of popup  but it  is not working properly.
  please  help if you have any idea.I am providing the code so that you 
   can understand my problem.

```
       public static native void hello()
        /*-{

                 var id=Math.floor((Math.random()*100)+1); 
                 var label=$doc.createElement("Label");
                var labelText = $doc.createTextNode("CLICK ME :: "+id);
                label.id=id;

               label.appendChild(labelText);

               body.appendChild(label);     

              var popup=$doc.createElement("div");
              var popuptext=$doc.createTextNode(".....");
              popup.className="pop";

              popup.appendChild(popuptext);

                     var hideDelayTimer=null;
                     var hideDelay=100;

        label.addEventListener("mouseover",function(e)
                     {      


                 if(hideDelayTimer)
                 clearTimeout(hideDelayTimer);
                 label.appendChild(popup);
                 var position= popup.offsetTop;
                 var width=popup.offsetWidth;
                 var width1=label.offsetWidth;
                 var position1=label.offsetHeight;
                 var position2=label.offsetTop;
                 var positionpop=popup.offsetHeight;

                 height=position-positionpop;

                 if(height<=0||height<positionpop)
                 {
                     alert("no change");
                 }

                 else
                 {   
                       hehe=height-80;
                       alert(hehe);
                      if(height>0 && height>=positionpop)
                      { 
                        popup.setAttribute("style","top:"+hehe+"px");
                        alert("bye");
                      }
                 }

          });

         label.addEventListener("mouseout",function()
           {

                  hideDelayTimer=setTimeout(function()
                 {
                      label.removeChild(popup);

                 },hideDelay);

           });   
    }-*/;
```

This is my css code.

```
         .pop
    {
        border:1px solid black ;
        width:500px;
        height:140px;
       background-color: #d1d4d5;
       position:absolute;
       z-index: 1;
       cursor:pointer;
    }
```

Comment: Are you saying you want to have the popup adjust itself with respect to the screen?

Comment: In my code the popup is not appending just above the label ,it is appending at the desired position of heh that I have given.and I want to append it above the label

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is one problem in your code. You can't refer `body` directly in GWT JSNI. For more info have a look at [Writing Native JavaScript Methods in GWT](http://www.gwtproject.org/doc/latest/DevGuideCodingBasicsJSNI.html)

Use

```
$doc.body.appendChild(label);
```

instead of

```
body.appendChild(label);
```

---

--EDIT--

Sample code:

```
label.addEventListener("mouseover", function(e) {

    if (hideDelayTimer)
        clearTimeout(hideDelayTimer);
    label.appendChild(popup);

    var labelHeight = label.offsetHeight;
    var labelTop = label.offsetTop;
    var windowHeight = $wnd.innerHeight;
    var popupHeight = popup.offsetHeight;

    if (labelTop + labelHeight + popupHeight > windowHeight) {
        popup.setAttribute("style", "top:" + (labelTop - popupHeight)
                + "px");
    }

});
```

Comment: thanks,but it is not affecting my code either by writing $doc.body.appendChild(label) or body.appendChild(label)

Comment: thanks,but is this useful for setting position dynamically up and down to each label.

Comment: Correct me if I am wrong. You want to append it above the label. Right? Let me code it for you.

Comment: I want to append it above when the screen is less at below and when the screen it less at above it append below. my code is append the popup above but not just above the label.

Comment: Please have a loop at my post. I have used `window.innerHeight` to calculate about the position of pop-up.

Comment: hi,can you please clear my one doubt....if the popup.offsetTop calculate the height from the top of the browser start to that of popup..thanks in advance